# Identifying columns by position rather than name

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this in my code:

```
 _currentData = dta.map(function(d) {
         return {
             "Filter_1": d.Company, 
             "Filter_2": d.Continent,
             "Dt": parseDate(d.Dt),
             "amount": +d.NumUsers 
         };
     })
```

So dta is a table of data with 4 columns - their headers are `Company/Continent/Dt/NumUsers`

Is it possible to identify the columns by their position rather than header. I tried the following but neither works:

```
 _currentData = dta.map(function(d) {
         return {
             "Filter_1": d[0], 
             "Filter_2": d.Continent,
             "Dt": parseDate(d.Dt),
             "amount": +d.NumUsers 
         };
     })

 _currentData = dta.map(function(d) {
         return {
             "Filter_1": d.columns(0), 
             "Filter_2": d.Continent,
             "Dt": parseDate(d.Dt),
             "amount": +d.NumUsers 
         };
     })
```

Comment: so `dta` is the array of objects received from `d3.csv`?

Comment: @whytheq I edited the tittle to make this question easier to find for future users, I hope you agree.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado no problem at all sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard answer would be **no**. Since in your `map` function `d` is an **object**, like this...

```
{Company: "foo", Continent: "bar", Dt: "baz", NumUsers: "foobar"}
```

... and **not** an array, it's impossible to tell who is the first and who is last: you cannot guarantee the order of the properties in an object.

However, using D3 v4, there is a way to identify the column by its position... **if** you're using `d3.csv` or `d3.tsv` to load the data:

Both these functions create an *array property* named `columns`, with the first row of the data (the headers)  as an array. So, you just need:

```
var columns = data.columns;
```

Which, for your data, will be this:

```
["Company", "Continent", "Dt", "NumUsers"]
```

After that, use that `columns` array in your `map` function:

```
var _currentData = data.map(d => {
    return {
        "Filter_1": d[columns[0]],
        "Filter_2": d[columns[1]],
        "Dt": d[columns[2]],
        "amount": d[columns[3]]
    };
});
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var data = d3.csvParse(d3.select("#csv").text());

var columns = data.columns;

var _currentData = data.map(d => {
  return {
    "Filter_1": d[columns[0]],
    "Filter_2": d[columns[1]],
    "Dt": d[columns[2]],
    "amount": d[columns[3]]
  };
});

console.log(_currentData);
```

```css
pre{
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<pre id="csv">Company,Continent,Dt,NumUsers
foo,bar,baz,foobar
foo2,bar2,baz2,foobar2
foo3,bar3,baz3,foobar3
foo4,bar4,baz4,foobar4
</pre>
```